# CAN Communication: Knowing Which Node Transmitted Data

Tags: can-bus

I am new to CAN communication and one of my tasks is to use a CANalyzer to learn what message IDs are being used for a product and what data is being sent/received.

The product has multiple nodes that can send/receive CAN messages. I know CAN messages are broadcasted to all the nodes, but the part I'm having a hard time determining is which node transmitted the message and which nodes received it.

So, for example, if I have 3 CAN nodes, is there a way I can determine that Node 1 sent the message and Node 2/3 are receiving the message?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you can't know this by listening to the CAN bus alone. The same old story whenever someone asks about data on "CAN bus" is: what application layer protocol is it using? "CAN bus" doesn't tell you jack, it's just the specification physical and data link layers. The concept of identifying individual nodes does not exist on the data link layer, only on the application layer.

There's two possible ways for you to tell:

- If you know the application layer used on top of the physical CAN bus and know that it uses node id, then you can tell which node that is sending what data by decoding the application-layer protocol.
- On each node, you can sniff the Tx signal between the MCU and CAN transceiver with an oscilloscope. That one only goes active when a node is sending or ACK:ing. Most modern scopes has a CAN frame decoder feature, saving you the head ache of decoding the frames manually.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. I am dealing with a black box set up, so I'm essentially reverse engineering a product. If there's nothing in the signal that I can use to determine the direction, then I will have to resort to monitoring the Tx signal directly.

Edit (Hit enter too soon). 

Thank you very much for the confirmation!

Comment: @KyleMuehlegg People without CAN knowledge often think it's sufficient to reverse engineer something by watching what identifiers and data that's present. But a properly designed CAN bus also has load and real-time requirements, such as how often a certain message is supposed to be sent. So reverse engineering and then try to mimic the behavior is questionable practice. Been there, done that: you end up with a dirty hack that might be unreliable or dangerous.

Comment: Yes, that's the feeling I'm getting as I research more and more into CAN. The boss wants us to try, so I suppose I'll do what you recommended with a CANalyzer to help and just hope for the best. 
*shrugs*

Comment: @KyleMuehlegg I've spent considerable amounts of time trying to explain this to some know-it-all boss. The problem isn't hacking into an existing CAN bus and control something by mimicking another node, I can do that easily enough. The problem is to claim that the hack is a safe solution that we can roll out in production, without knowing the timing considerations of the bus and without consulting/getting an approval from the original equipment manufacturer. Should that system fail and cause an accident, then the one who made the hack is completely screwed.